Why \tolerance=10000 has no effect?
On p.29 of TeXbook it is said that a tolerance of 10000 will never produce an overfull box (unless something strange occurs like an unhyphenatable word that
is wider than the column itself), but running TeX on this example gives Overfull \hbox. Why? (By the way, if we put blank line before second
"Once...", overfull messages disappear. Why?)
\hsize=1.5cm
\parindent=0pt
\tolerance=10000 \hbadness=10000
Once upon a time, in a distant
  galaxy called \"O\"o\c c,
there lived a computer
named R.~J. Drofnats.
Once upon a time, in a distant
  galaxy called \"O\"o\c c,
there lived a computer
named R.~J. Drofnats.
\bye


@cfr yes, but it is not applicable here

@cfr added second part

tidy up ... ...

It is very interesting problem. The first sentence is only underfull but the second one has overfull boxes.
When we set \tracingparagraphs=1 then we can see that the total demerits t exceeds 1000000000 at breakpoint 17 and TeX starts different behavior from this point. May be, we can look to the source of TeX but now, I have no time to deal with this.
Note that if we put nonzero \emergencystretch, for example \emergencystretch=20pt then we can see that TeX runs @emergencypass just after the total demerits exceeds 1000000000 (i.e at breakpoint 17) and the result is without overfull boxes.
Edit
The section 833 of the TeX source introduces a constant awful_bad which is 2^{30}-1 = 1073741823. The algorithms are implemented that the total demerits never exceeds this constant. See the section 833 of tex.web and next sections for more detailed information (including large Knut's comments).
In your example, the berakpoint @@17 (from listing of \traingparagraphs=1) has total demerits 1002001316 and next additional demerits d=100002500 yields to the sum greater than 2^{30}-1. TeX doesn't calculate such sum and starts its different behavior.

Interesting research. I guess that Knuth decided that when a paragraphs earns so big an amount of demerits, it's useless to try and make it “nice” (which would also require extending the range of integers).

Yes. It feels like TeX behaves like a human being in this case. When, after a certain period of effort, it finds that it is pointless, it gives up and does not try any further.
